# how to Create simple stored procedure which returns resultset in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Create simple stored procedure which returns resultset in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `something`.`PName` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Something`.`PName` (cid INT)
BEGIN

  SELECT * FROM table;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

----Very simple store procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCountry()
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM Country;

    END //
DELIMITER ;
```